# How to keep track of daily mobile data limit?

Tags: 8.1, data-usage, datasense

Using the Data Sense app, I can set a number of different data limits (pre-paid, monthly, unlimited), but what seems to be missing is a daily limit. This makes it hard to keep track of such limits when necessary (e.g. my carrier imposes a daily data limit when roaming).

Assuming this capability isn't present in the OS and simply disabled by my carrier (which I understand is always a possibility with network-related settings and features), is there any other way to keep track of daily data usage? With a third-party app, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd party don't currently have access to this, so I think answer to your question is - No, its not currently possible.

Probably this's a great idea you should create on [WP User Voice](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/)